# how to create variable-length fields yasnippet snippet

Tags: yasnippet

I'm trying to create a snippet that generate a python docstring.
I have a function that parses the current python function for arguments. now I want to use this function in the snippet to generate the list of fields for arguments.

for example if I have a function like this:

```python
def test_func (arg1, arg2, arg3 ): 
    pass
```

using the snippet in this function should prompt me for something like this:

```python
"""
...
Arguments:
  arg1: # {$1} prompt for the first argument 
  arg2: # {$2} prompt for second argument
  arg3: # {$3} prompt for third argument 
"""
```